# Wordpress add_post_meta and global color array

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a custom css class to each new post (background color). I do this by adding a custom field with add_post_data and run the function every time a new post is generated.

I have an Array where the css color classes are defined like 'blue','aqua', 'dark-purple' etc.

It all works fine only I can't figure out how to assign the next color value in the array when a new post is generated.

Also when the last color is used, the array re-starts from the first position.
Would you have an idea as how to achieve this?

How would this function know what the next color is? Would it need to peek into the previous post?

In functions.php:

```
// Define color on each new post
function set_post_color($post_ID){
    $colors = array('blue','aqua','dark-purple','red','orange','yellow','light-green','dusty-blue','bright-pink','dark-green','dusty-purple');
    $current_field_value = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'css-color-class', true);
    $value = (string)rand(0, 100); // this should be the next color in the color array

    // Only add field if it does not already exist and the post is not a revision
    if($current_field_value == '' && !wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)){
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'css-color-class', $value, true);
    }

    return $post_ID;
}

// Hook up the function
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'set_post_color');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, look into the DB for the color assigned to your last inserted post and then pick the next color to your new post, or you can maintain an option with the next color you need to assign.

This has the disavantage that you need to maintain manually this value actualized, but you can use the default functions to get, add and update options:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: This was just what I needed. Indeed I overlooked the DB options table. Thanks.